# php: Get html source code with cURL

Tags: php, html, curl

How can I get the html source code of `http://www.example-webpage.com/file.html` without using `file_get_contents()`?

I need to know this because on some webhosts `allow_url_fopen` is disabled so you can't use `file_get_contents()`. Is it possible to get the html file's source with cURL (if cURL support  is enabled)? If so, how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example-webpage.com/file.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I would only recommend this for small files. Big files are read as a whole and are likely to produce a memory error.

---

**EDIT:** after some discussion in the comments we found out that the problem was that the server couldn't resolve the host name and the page was in addition a HTTPS resource so here comes your temporary solution (until your server admin fixes the name resolving).

what i did is just pinging graph.facebook.com to see the IP address, replace the host name with the IP address and instead specify the header manually. This however renders the SSL certificate invalid so we have to suppress peer verification.

```
//$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/19165649929?fields=name";
$url = "https://66.220.146.224/19165649929?fields=name";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: graph.facebook.com'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Keep in mind that the IP address might change and this is an error source. you should also do some error handling using `curl_error();`.

Comment: John, if this isn't working then check your URL.  Also, don't forget the curl_close($ch) at the end.

Comment: Does it work with a plain text file instead of a html file? I tested it with a plain text file - and I get a blank page.

Comment: youre right closing up curl is not a bad idea, ill investigate the use case with the text file. maby you have an url for me (because theres practically no difference but there may be another error...)?

Comment: okay downlaoding http://www.facebook.com/robots.txt worked fine, can you give me the url that doesnt work?

Comment: try this please: https://graph.facebook.com/19165649929?fields=name
that does not work for me. Obviously it's also accessable via "http"

Comment: its https, not http. it works here with the example above but the ssl settins may be version specific! please try this: var_dump(curl_error($ch)); before curl_close and tell me what it outputs!

Comment: so your server cant resolve the ip adress. you should contact your server administrator he should set up correct dns resolving. theres nothing wrong with your code. the only solution i now know or you without correcting this server issue is to directly get the data from the ip adress and send the host header, but you will have to deal with ssl warnings. by the way it would be nice if you upvoted this :)

Comment: dont give up just yet, i modified the answer and posted a temporary solution for you!

Comment: `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` is no longer required (since version 5.1.3, which I really hope no one is using).

Answer (score 3):

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Source:  http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/php-curl-allow-url-fopen/

Answer (score 3):

Try http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php :)

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

As the documentation says:

> The basic idea behind the cURL functions is that you **initialize a cURL session using the curl_init(),** then you can set all your options for the transfer via the curl_setopt(), then you can execute the session with the curl_exec() and then you **finish off your session using the curl_close()**.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool in Github that could possibly be a solution to this question. https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ 
I hope that will be useful