# How to get source of this page?

Tags: php

### i use this code to get html source

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$html = file_get_html("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
 echo $html;
```

But when I want to get the source from [Here](http://www.madaraneh.com/)! I don't correct response and I get something like these characters:

```
F"H�H�VDPJ����˲59��[��v���R        �N��T�E"#nܸ��s��=�  ��������?�?
```

Answer (score 1):

file_get_html() is most probably used in [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) class. Either include that class, or better  [use curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592300/1437261) to fetch the content.

If you comment the line where you have set the header, you will actually see an error notice which gets converted to the gibberish content due to the header set.

Comment: Woops. Nice find! Changed down to up. Removing comment.