# Run original external HTML in PHP

Tags: php

I have some html files stored in AWS S3, and I access them with AWS CloudFront.

I need to call them from my PHP code, like that:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://mycdnurl.com/myhtmlfile.html');
```

It works, but it ignores all line breaks and sometimes it breaks the code because of some piece of javascript code inside the html like that:

```
// some javascript comment
var test = test
```

Turns into:

```
// some javascript comment var test = test
```

If I access the file directly from browser, it works nice. But I need to call from PHP without iframe.

I tried to search but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound right since `file_get_contents()` preserves the file content including newlines.

- Perhaps your file contains the wrong type of line-breaks, e.g. Unix, Windows, Mac?
- There might be an issue with the encoding as well (I doubt it).
  Try loading the file contents as UTF-8 with a fallback to your other encoding, e.g. Latin 1, if applicable.

  ```
  function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
      $content = file_get_contents($fn);
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
  }
  ```
- If nothing works, you could try cURL instead of file_get_contents(). [Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592270/php-get-html-source-code-with-curl).